# LinearGradientBrush with degree direction

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

I want to paint the background of a form with gradient using the LinearGradientBrush; but I have troubles using degrees.

Basically, I want using linear gradient in diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter for that:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
  Using br As New LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, _
                                      Color.LightBlue, Color.DarkBlue, _
                                      LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, Me.ClientRectangle)
  End Using

  MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

The enumerations available for `LinearGradientMode` are:

```
BackwardDiagonal
ForwardDiagonal
Horizontal
Vertical
```